# json data in variable and display in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have stored JSON data in variable. but while retrieving its showing unexpected token o.

```
var somejson = "[{ \"key1\" : \"<header class=\"main-header dark-bg\"><div class=\"row\"></div></header>\"},{\"key2\" : \"<div class=\"row content clearfix worldwide dark-bg t--bg-5\"></div>\"}]";

var mainObject = JSON.parse(somejson);
  console.log(mainObject);
  for (var key in mainObject) {
    //console.log("key"+key);
          var innerObject = mainObject[key];
          //console.log("inner object "+innerObject);
          for (var innerKey in innerObject) {
            var t = innerObject[innerKey];
            console.log(t);
}
}
```

Can some one help me where i'm wrong, i'm gettting unexpected token o error. I searched for solution but couldn't able to resolve. please help me on this

Comment: JSON string is invalid thats what error says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your JSON data is invalid** since you are having `"main-header dark-bg"` inside the value of key `key1` **without escaping those double quotes**.

Make it

```
var somejson = "[{ \"key1\" : \"<header class=\\\"main-header dark-bg\\\"><div class=\\\"row\\\"></div></header>\"},{\"key2\" : \"<div class=\\\"row content clearfix worldwide dark-bg t--bg-5\\\"></div>\"}]";
```

Or use single quotes for attribute values inside the key value

```
var somejson = "[{ \"key1\" : \"<header class='main-header dark-bg'><div class='row'></div></header>\"},{\"key2\" : \"<div class='row content clearfix worldwide dark-bg t--bg-5'></div>\"}]";
```

Comment: _gurvinder372 first one worked for me. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make your json as follows:

```
"[{ "key1" : "<header class='main-header dark-bg'><div class='row'></div></header>"},{"key2" : "<div class='row content clearfix worldwide dark-bg t--bg-5'></div>"}]"
```